# pngs for IE, jpgs for all other browsers?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several jpgs that are being masked with a png to create the final "[jpgs with alpha channels](http://hedgerwow.blogspot.com/2010/10/re-jpegs-with-alpha-channels.html)".  This is working in all browsers except, of course, IE.

I would really love to use jpgs as the file size for pngs is 4-5 times larger.

How can I best swap ".jpg" for ".png" for IE? I know I could use 2 images in the same div and toggle their display properties in css using an IE specific stylesheet, but AFAIK this means that both images will *load* in all browsers meaning the load time is made even worse.

I'm happy to use javascript/jquery. Anything really to make it work! Is it possible simply to swap the file extension for IE?

MTIA :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [IE's conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send slightly different markup (e.g., different `img` tags) to IE vs. the other browsers. E.g.:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<img src="foo">
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
<img src="bar">
<![endif]>
```

...which sends the "foo" image to IE and the "bar" image to everything else.

That answers the question you actually asked about giving different files to the browser. But I can't help but think there's a better way to solve the underlying problem. I don't quite understand what it is you're doing with the images, but if you post a separate question saying what you're doing and asking for a solution (which may or may not be to send a different file type to IE), hopefully people can help.

Comment: Or <!--[if IE]><img src="image.png"><![endif]-->  <!--[if !IE]><img src="image.jpg"><![endif]-->

Comment: Thanks. Using IE conditional comments has fixed things. As a brief explanation - I'm coding someone else's design and it includes several oddly-shaped galleries placed over an image. Each image within the galleries has a transparent area. Gifs' 256 colours are no good, pngs are too large and jpgs have no transparency. The best I could come up with was the 'jpgs with alpha' solution. It works fine. Thanks so much for your help (again!).